# Cancel a users PayPal subscription via python sdk with payer email

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I currently have a paypal subscription form that I get notifications in my backend via paypals ipn to my python backend.  This works fine, what I now have issues with is when a user cancels I have to go manually into paypal and put in their email to cancel.

I know PayPal has a sdk, but their documentation is a bit confusing as it says I need the billing agreement.  I haven't been able to find a example of a simple call using their sdk to simply cancel a subscription via the payer email.  Does this exist? is this possible?

Comment: I read somewhere that paypal subscriptions can only be cancelled from the paypal website. You can add instructions to cancel on your website though

Comment: really? It can't be automated?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/manage_subscriptions/ it doesn't look like it